# Flutter - getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() : How to get the path in android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, flutter

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
```

In android native code, I use `getCacheDir()`

How do i get the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` path in android?
When i print `getFilesDir()` in android it is not matching with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`

Please tell me the equivalent in android and iOS.

Thanks

Comment: Try `getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.documents)`

Comment: I searched in android and found that `This method was deprecated in API level 29.`

Comment: As far as i know, Its only support Android :(

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin. The function [getTemporaryDirectory()](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getTemporaryDirectory.html) uses `getCacheDir()` on Android, while it uses `NSCachesDirectory` on iOS.

If you need storage access for user-generated data, you can use [getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html). If the data is not user-generated, you can use [getApplicationSupportDirectory()](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationSupportDirectory.html).